# scp команда в linux скачивает файл, но в папке его нет

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, scp

Качаю файл с удалённого сервера по ssh вот так

```
sudo scp root@blablabla.ru:/etc/letsencrypt/live/blabla/fullchain.pem home\denis\Документы\web\blabla\vps\
```

Ввожу пароль, нажимаю enter после чего вижу

```
fullchain.pem                                 100% 5624    11.4MB/s   00:00
```

Но в папке файл не появлятся. Пробовал 100500 вариантов слешей, путей и прочие мелочи менял в команде. Результат один и тот же.

Кто знает, в чем проблема?

Comment: Есть только один правильный вариант слешей: `/home/denis/...`

Comment: начальный слешь /home/...

Comment: @AlexeyTen, ну утилиты Samba понимают оба варианта (с учётом экранирование в shell). И браузеры вроде бы тоже, но это я мог и запамятовать.

Comment: Если ставлю обычный слеш, а не обратный, в дериктории локальной, то мне пишит, что файл или дерриктория не найдены

Comment: У вас должен в текущем каталоге появиться файл, начинающийся на home и заканчивающийся на vps. Покажите вывод ls сразу после scp. И не сомневайтесь: есть только один правильный вариант слешей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена.
Дело было в том, что я производил авторизацию ssh на сервер и после в этом же терминале пытался выполнить

```
sudo scp root@blablabla.ru:/etc/letsencrypt/live/blabla/fullchain.pem home\denis\Документы\web\blabla\vps\
```

Что естественно приводило к ошибке т.к. на сервере нету `home/denis/Документы/web/blabla/vps`

После, я запустил из локального терминала не подключенного к серверу ту же команду с указанием нужного порта сервера. Обычно это 22, но на моём сервере это 49434 и всё получилось

```
sudo scp -P 49434 root@blablabla.ru:/etc/letsencrypt/live/blabla/fullchain.pem home/denis/Документы/web/blabla/vps
```

И как выше сказал @AlexeyTen обратные слеши не нужны